# Category of objects over the terminal object is isomorphic to the original category

Tags: category-theory

This is an exercise from Mac Lane. Here's my attempted solution: 
Let the terminal object $t$ of the category $C$ be given, by definition for each object $k\in C$, there is a unique arrow $k\to t$ hence the two categories $C$ and $(C\downarrow t)$ have identical objects. Then, let any two objects $k_1,k_2\in C$ and $f:k_1\to t$,$g:k_2\to t$ and let $h$ be any morphism $h:k_1\to k_2$, since the arrows $f,g$ are unique, the triangle of $k_1,k_2,t$ with edges $h,f,g$ must commute hence $h$ is again an arrow in the comma category, completing the proof since arrows in the comma category are contained in the original category.

Comment: That looks fine to me.